# Can I answer collective questions with a non-collective answer?

Tags: support, collectives

I'm looking at this [AWS collective question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717305/run-a-remote-script-using-shebang-in-linux), and this has me a bit puzzled, as I'm not much of an expert on AWS, but the question here would be very helpful for a problem on my own project that I'm trying to solve.

Given that it is in a collective, can I:

- Answer it generically
- Craft a similar but more generic question, give it as a community wiki question, and link the two
- Something else?

Comment: FWIW, since that question wasn't even about AWS I have removed that tag.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question, even if it's based on a misunderstanding. I have a feeling that a lot of people have this same misconception of what Collectives are and how they work, so this seems like a really good question to have here. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Questions in tags that belong to a collective are treated exactly the same as any other question on the site. Collectives do not change the way how answering, moderation, etc. works.

Collectives don't own questions; they are just a group of tags. When any of the tags is applied to a question, the collective is shown.

Comment: Yeah, I fully misunderstood collective questions as special questions rather than tagged questions.